Calculating 99th Percentile of Fst values for SNPs within gene
I used SNP data and calculated Fst using the Popgenome R package to identify SNPs that have diverged between bacterial populations.
Afterwards, I want to calculate the 99th percentile (P99) of Fst values for SNPs within a single gene and further investigate SNPs that exceed the P99 threshold.
Should zero and negative Fst values be included when calculating P99?

You haven't provided any example input files or code, but calculating the 99th percentile in R is a fairly simple process using the quantile function:
> data <- rnorm(1000)
> quantile(data, 0.99)
     99% 
2.261149 

If you want to filter out negative or zero Fst values, this can be done using logical filters:
> quantile(data[data > 0], 0.99)
     99% 
2.435389 

Whether or not it makes sense to do this filtering will be dataset specific, and you haven't provided any additional context about your data, so there's no way to appropriately answer that. This is why we put the recommendations into the help for asking questions; it makes answers better.
